# How to slide Activity with Animation Effect in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-animation

I am working on an Android app. I want to implement such animation on activity that if we leave `activity A` then it should slide to left and new `activity B` should slide in from right. And again when I leave current `activity B` it should slide to right as well and previous `activity A` should slide in from Left to Right. How is that possible ?

By the way I am using following code but it doesn't do anything..

`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out);`

I have written some XML code for Animation slides as below :

***slide_left_in.xml :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

***slide_left_out.xml :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />

</set>
```

Your Help would be appreciate.
Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

For the following animation you require these **4 anim xml**.....

right_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

right_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

left_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

left_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

and use these code with the AcitvityA ...

```
            intent = new Intent(this, AcitvityB.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition( R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
```

and use these in AcitvityB for BACK

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition( R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out);

    }
```

Output:-

[image: o]

**NOTE:- If you need it opposite animation just change right instead of left and vice versa ......**

Comment: I have already tried this and I don't know why this code is not working for me.

Comment: It hangs my app and do not open another activity. :(

Comment: than it is problem of device ?? try with different device

Comment: I updated the image which is working on my android and emulator .... May be some problem with your code ....

Comment: same code followed and also tried on another device. I don't know where I am doing wrong, or why it is not happening with my code :(